# Apache Kafka Connect flat JSon Array to objects

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm importing data from MS SQL Server table to a Apache Kafka topic with Kafka Connect.

The change column is a json array that I'd like to flat and send in multiple events.

Table records look like this:

```
id      table       change                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3       dbo.Pets    {"change":[{"OP":"UPDATE", "Id":"3", "Name":"Rufus","Type":"Cat","Number":"10482638"}, {"OP":"INSERT", "Id":"", "Name":"Misifu","Type":"Reddy","Number":"85745874"}]}
```

And what I like to insert in the topic is:

```
id      table       change                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3       dbo.Pets    {"OP":"UPDATE", "Id":"3", "Name":"Rufus","Type":"Cat","Number":"10482638"}
3       dbo.Pets    {"OP":"INSERT", "Id":"", "Name":"Misifu","Type":"Reddy","Number":"85745874"}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Which Kafka Connect connector are you using?

Comment: Confluent JDBC Connector https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/index.html

Comment: So the JDBC connector is pulling from a SQL Server CDC table? If so, you probably want to look at how to configure SQL Server's CDC to split out the events. Kafka Connect will only be able do  one row -> one message.

Comment: A trigguer inserts data changes in this table. Split out the events in the trigger slq code is the approach I have done. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below with your solution

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to decompose the message into the sql trigger wit the appropiate format, no other option. Thanks to everybody :)

Comment: Hello! Please tell us more, how did you do it? I have a similar problem! Please show an example of the code or provide a link.